# Is there a macro for creating fast Iterators from generator-like functions in julia?

Tags: iterator, julia, iterable

Coming from python3 to Julia one would love to be able to write **fast** iterators as a function with produce/yield syntax or something like that.

Julia's macros seem to suggest that one could build a macro which transforms such a "generator" function into an julia iterator.
[It even seems like you could easily **inline** iterators written in function style, which is a feature the Iterators.jl package also tries to provide for its specific iterators https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl#the-itr-macro-for-automatic-inlining-in-for-loops ]

Just to give an example of what I have in mind:

```
@asiterator function myiterator(as::Array)
  b = 1
  for (a1, a2) in zip(as, as[2:end])
    try
      @produce a1[1] + a2[2] + b
    catch exc
    end
  end
end

for i in myiterator([(1,2), (3,1), 3, 4, (1,1)])
   @show i
end
```

where `myiterator` should ideally create a fast iterator with as low overhead as possible. And of course this is only one specific example. I ideally would like to have something which works with all or almost all generator functions.

The currently recommended way to transform a generator function into an iterator is via Julia's Tasks, at least to my knowledge. However they also seem to be way slower then pure iterators. For instance if you can express your function with the simple iterators like `imap`, `chain` and so on (provided by [`Iterators.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Iterators.jl) package) this seems to be highly preferable.

Is it theoretically possible in julia to build a macro converting generator-style functions into flexible **fast** iterators?

Extra-Point-Question: If this is possible, could there be a generic macro which inlines such iterators?

Comment: `Channel`s, which replace `Task`s in 0.6, should be substantially faster than `Task`s.

Comment: I haven't heard about them yet, and I read a lot documentations about julia. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Channels don't replace Tasks --- they're a mechanism that Tasks can use to communicate.

Answer (score 4):

Some iterators of this form can be written like this:

```
myiterator(as) = (a1[1] + a2[2] + 1 for (a1, a2) in zip(as, as[2:end]))
```

This code can (potentially) be inlined.

To fully generalize this, it is in theory possible to write a macro that converts its argument to continuation-passing style (CPS), making it possible to suspend and restart execution, giving something like an iterator. Delimited continuations are especially appropriate for this (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimited_continuation). The result is a big nest of anonymous functions, which might be faster than Task switching, but not necessarily, since at the end of the day it needs to heap-allocate a similar amount of state.

I happen to have an example of such a transformation here (in femtolisp though, not Julia): https://github.com/JeffBezanson/femtolisp/blob/master/examples/cps.lsp
This ends with a `define-generator` macro that does what you describe. But I'm not sure it's worth the effort to do this for Julia.

Answer (score 2):

Python-style generators – which in Julia would be closest to yielding from tasks – involve a fair amount of inherent overhead. You have to switch tasks, which is non-trivial and cannot straightforwardly be eliminated by a compiler. That's why Julia's iterators are based on functions that transform one typically immutable, simple state value, and another. Long story short: no, I do not believe that this transformation can be done automatically.

Answer (score 2):

After thinking a lot how to translate python generators to Julia without loosing much performance, I implemented and tested a library of higher level functions which implement Python-like/Task-like generators in a continuation-style. https://github.com/schlichtanders/Continuables.jl

Essentially, the idea is to regard Python's `yield` / Julia's `produce` as a function which we take from the outside as an extra parameter. I called it `cont` for continuation. Look for instance on this reimplementation of a range

```
crange(n::Integer) = cont -> begin
  for i in 1:n
    cont(i)
  end
end
```

You can simply sum up all integers by the following code

```
function sum_continuable(continuable)
  a = Ref(0)
  continuable() do i
    a.x += i
  end
  a.x
end

# which simplifies with the macro Continuables.@Ref to
@Ref function sum_continuable(continuable)
  a = Ref(0)
  continuable() do i
    a += i
  end
  a
end

sum_continuable(crange(4))  # 10
```

As you hopefully agree, you can work with continuables almost like you would have worked with generators in python or tasks in julia. Using `do` notation instead of `for` loops is kind of the one thing you have to get used to.

This idea takes you really really far. The only standard method which is not purely implementable using this idea is `zip`. All the other standard higher-level tools work just like you would hope.

The performance is unbelievably faster than Tasks and even faster than Iterators in some cases (notably the naive implementation of `Continuables.cmap` is orders of magnitude faster than `Iterators.imap`). Check out the Readme.md of the github repository https://github.com/schlichtanders/Continuables.jl for more details.

---

EDIT: To answer my own question more directly, there is no need for a macro `@asiterator`, just use continuation style directly.

```
mycontinuable(as::Array) = cont -> begin
  b = 1
  for (a1, a2) in zip(as, as[2:end])
    try
      cont(a1[1] + a2[2] + b)
    catch exc
    end
  end
end

mycontinuable([(1,2), (3,1), 3, 4, (1,1)]) do i
   @show i
end
```